# Search Criteria for the products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, search-criteria

I have gone through the `Search Criteria` functionality to filter the products, for this I have created the custom attribute`smart_search` **multiselect** attribute. And I have written some code for filter those items.

But it is not working for me, for this I written below stuff.

```
<?php

namespace ABCCompany\CustomerSearch\Observer;

class RedirectCustomerSearch implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface{



    /**
    * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
    */
    protected $_productRepository;


    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
    */
    protected $_searchCriteria;


    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ){
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    public function getSmartSearch($search){

        $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteria->addFilter('smart_search', $search)->create();
        $result = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        return $result->getItems() 

    }

}
```

In `smart_search` options have **blue color, binding, Comics** etc.. I have passed **blue color**, but it is returning nothing.

Could you please suggest me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As your custom attribute 'smart_search' is a multiselect attribute, on the creation of the search criteria the value that you have to pass is the option value and not the option label like **blue color**. Additionally, the default condition type of the addFilter function in 'eq'. As your custom attribute is multiselect you have to change this to 'finset'.

Try something like below, where $search is the option value of your custom attribute.

```
$searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteria->addFilter('smart_search', $search, 'finset')->create();
```